# how should be used a service "factory" in a provider of angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, provider

I'm trying to use a service "factory" in service "provider".
How is the best way to do it.
I'm working with different modules. but it is generates a mistake me when I import the service to the new function.
What is the best way to reuse or inject services in a service "provider".

http://jsfiddle.net/aurigadl/facgT/5/

```
var moduleService = angular.module('templatesServices', []);
moduleService.factory('templateSrv',['$q', function($q){ 
    return {
        data: function(){
            console.log('In factory');
            return 2000;
        }
    }
}])

function  login(templateSrv){
  this.$get     = angular.noop;   
  this.getAcces = function(){
    return 'some data';
  };
}   

login.$inject = ['templatesServices'];

angular.module('loginProvider', ['templatesServices']).provider('login', ['caliopewebTemplateSrv',login]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providers are available in a phase before any solid services or other components are ready, so you won't be able to inject your service directly into the provider.

You can, however, inject services into the `$get` function of your provider, used when you actually instantiate a service. So your `loginProvider` cannot access `templateSrv` but your `login` service can do, so long as the module in which `templateSrv` is defined 'requires' that in which `loginProvider` is defined. It appears to be doing this in your example (`angular.module('loginProvider', ['templatesServices'])`) but the fiddle seems very different.

```
var templateModule = angular.module('templateModule', []);
templateModule.factory('templateSrv',[function(){ 
    return {
        // ...
    };
}]);

function loginProvider(){
    this.$get = ['templateSrv', 'otherService', function(templateSrv, otherService) {
      // Use templateSrv/otherService (from templateModule or loginModule) somehow
    }];
    this.getAccess = function(){
        return 'some data';
    };
}

angular.module('loginModule', ['templateModule'])
    .provider('login', loginProvider);
```

I don't quite follow your intentions so I can't give much more information, but I hope this helps.

Sources:

- http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module
- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$provide

Comment: Yes the idea is to use the service "factory" in service "provider".
This is useful when you need setup the module and can only use service "provider" with other services that you have.

runing http://jsfiddle.net/aurigadl/facgT/9/